# How to attach the language in question to the word "Muttersprachler"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-structure

Silly question, but useful I hope:

Suppose you speak, say, Portuguese but you are, say, Brazilian. So you are a non-Portuguese having Portuguese as mother tongue.

How to express that optimally in German using the word *Muttersprachler*?

> 1. Ich bin {Portuguiesisch·portugiesisch} Muttersprachler
> 2. Ich bin portuguiesischer Muttersprachler
> 3. Ich bin Portugiesischmuttersprachler.

Neither convinces me.

- (1) In the first sentence, either choice appears to my eyes as a mistake. If you choose capital *P*, what does exactly mean that juxtaposition of words? If you little *p*, it's a grammatical mistake.
- (2) As for the second line, it would imply that I'm from Portugal, wouldn't it? It doesn't even express that I do speak Portuguese.
- (3) No idea if that concatenation is allowed.

Of course, the best solution is saying *Ich komme aus Brasilien* – but it should be possible to state this without giving that much information.

Comment: Ich bin Muttersprachler des Portugiesischen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft klingt gut! Ich hatte aber das nie gehört. Sagt man das auch in nicht-formelen Unterhaltungen?

Comment: Keep it simple: *"Portugiesisch ist meine Muttersprache"*

Comment: Die Frage geht wohl an Schweizer und Österreicher...

Comment: Wie ist das eigentlich im Englischen? "I'm English" heißt "Ich bin Engländer" but "I'm native English speaker" means that ~'you live in a country where English is spoken as first-language'.

Comment: The word "adjoint" is not a verb.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I think I've spread the mistake all over the answers `:S` (which I already edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you do not attach anything.

> "Meine Muttersprache ist Deutsch."
>
> "Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache."

Ansonsten kann und sollte man umschreiben:

> Diejenigen, die Deutsch als Muttersprache haben, schnitten beim PISA Deutsch-Test vergleichsweise gut ab.

statt Wortungetüme wie "deutschmuttersprachlich" zu schaffen.

Comment: Aber wofür existiert denn das Wort *Muttersprachler*. Es muss doch einen Grund geben. Wie nutzt man es? Muss ich einen Zusammenhang, einen Kontext, eine Sprache erwähnen, und nur dannach *Muttersprachler*?

Comment: @c.p. Zum Beispiel so: "Er spricht aber gut Deutsch!" - "Kein Wunder, er ist Muttersprachler."

Answer (score 3):

You asked how to attach the language, so I would choose the first solution with a hyphen:

> Ich bin Portugiesisch-Muttersprachler.

It’s easier to read than the third example and IMHO correct.

A formal way to express your language skills is *„Ich spreche Portugiesisch auf Muttersprachler-Niveau.“*

Comment: I did not down-vote, but I see the reasons: "Muttersprachler" is informal and should be avoided in formal discussions (like job interviews). Therefore, "Portugiesisch ist meine Muttersprache." is the best solution.

Comment: @Black Maybe, but c-p asked for a solution involving “Muttersprachler” (“... using the word Muttersprachler ...”), not alternatives.

Comment: Well, sometimes the best answer to a "how do I ..." question is "You don't.", of course along with a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

@Wrzl and @Vogel have alreade said two good solutions:

> "Ich bin Muttersprachler des Portugiesischen"

and

> "Portugiesisch ist meine Muttersprache".

Or, you use:

> "Ich spreche Portugiesisch muttersprachlich"

Answer (score 0):

While other acceptable choices have been highlighted, I'd say the best bet is "Ich bin portugiesischer Muttersprache" (literally "I'm of Portuguese native language")